# SPOJ MMAXPER::RECTANGLE PERIMETER

Tags: coding-style

http://www.spoj.com/problems/MMAXPER/

I don't know how to approach this problem since I am new to dp problems.
I am trying this approach but getting wrong answer::

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
  {
    int i,t,l,s,temp;
    long long int sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
      {
        scanf("%d %d",&s,&l);
        if(s>l) { temp=s; s=l; l=temp }
        if(i==1) sum=sum+l-s;
        else if(i==t && i%2==0) sum=sum+l+s;
        else if(i==t && i%2!=0) sum=sum+l-s;
        else if(i%2==0) sum=sum+2*l+s;
        else if(i%2!=0) sum=sum-2*s+l;
      }
    printf("%lld",sum);
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Think of the problem as to what choices you have to make. Since reordering is not allowed , the problem is simple . Let's see : for an ith rectangle you have 2 choices, either use it as it is or rotate it. If p(i,0) is the max perimeter with ith rectangle in the original position and p(i,1) denote the max perimeter if ith rectangle rotated then this yields a simple recurrence:

p(i,0)=max(p(i-1,0)+width(i)+|height(i)-height(i-1)|,p(i-1,1)+width(i)+|height(i)-width(i-1)|)

and

p(i,1)=max(p(i-1,0)+height(i)+|width(i)-height(i-1)|,p(i-1,1)+height(i)+|width(i)-width(i-1)|)

The final answer would be max(p(n-1,0),p(n-1,1))

with base cases p(0,0)=height(i) and p(0,1) = width(i);

Explanation:
Considering current ,i.e. ith rectangle the (i-1)th rectangle could have been placed normally or rotated. Taking the max of perimeters from both choices does the trick.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks :) It's really helpful to understand the solution